# Having some problems integrating TeamCity, GitHub and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, github, teamcity

**What I want to do:**

I want to set up Continuous Integration with Team City for a project that's hosted on GitHub.

**What's Currently Working**

I'm properly connected to GitHub.  Commits, pushing, etc etc all seem to be fine.
TeamCity is set up and I can kick off a build which will run and run my unit tests, but...

**What's Not Working**

When I do a TeamCity build, it looks like it's pulling down code from GitHub before doing the build or running unit tests.  I want to trigger a TC build when I do a commit, *before* it does the push to GitHub.  I don't really want it to pull any code out of GitHub before running the TC build. This doesn't seem to be working at all.

I've set up a  BuildTrigger which is a VCS Trigger.  I've checked the box that says Trigger a Build on Each Check-in.  I added a rule to the BuildTrigger with the VCS (Github) source and my username.

When I do a commit, I don't notice TC doing anything.  When I then push the commit to GitHub, TC doesn't do anything either.  I see no builds queuing or anything like that.

Any clues on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: When you do a commit with Git, it commits locally. If TeamCity is not set up to look at your local repository it will not trigger a build. It would only build when you pushed to Github. But from what I am reading, it sounds like that is not working either. So which are you trying to do, (1) run the build before pushing to Github and only push on success? or (2) run the build after pushing to Github?

Comment: I'd like to run the build before pushing to Github and only push on success.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at TeamCity's [pre-tested commit](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html) feature? It doesn't work exactly as you described you would like your workflow to operate, but it might be useful. I've used it with Subversion in the past and it works pretty well, I haven't used it with Git but [JetBrains state](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Pre-Tested+%28Delayed%29+Commit) it also works with Git.

However, the most common workflow for Git is to create feature/bugfix branches for everything you do, which allows you to commit and push freely, and merge to `master` when you are ready. GitHub makes the merge (and optional code review) step painless and TeamCity has built-in support to automatically build branches, see the [TeamCity documentation on feature branches](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Working+with+Feature+Branches) for specific details it provides.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon!  I suspected my workflow might be an issue, since I'm newish to Github.  I'll look into your recommendation!